# RStudio crashing when trying to use Python or Julia

Tags: python, r, crash, julia, rstudio

RStudio crashes for me whenever I try to use a different language engine like Python (anaconda or Python) or Julia. I can run `library(reticulate)` and `library(JuliaCall)` but when I actually start typing in a code chunk and try to execute python or julia code, the session crashes.

For Julia, I receive a first message that says,

> "Error Autosaving File. RStudio was unable to autosave this file. You
> may need to restart RStudio."

Then I get the

> "R Session Aborted"

message with the bomb and 'Start New Session' button. No code or other messaging is provided in RStudio.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled R, Python and Julia multiple times with no resolution.

When I try to use pure R and Julia, for example, below is the output (no messages for Python unfortunately). I am more interested in getting Python up and running in RStudio.

```
library(JuliaCall)
julia_setup()
```

> Julia version 1.6.3 at location
> /Applications/Julia-1.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin will be used.
>
> *** caught segfault *** address 0xfffffffffffffff8, cause 'memory not
> mapped'
>
> Traceback:  1: juliacall_initialize(.julia$dll_file, .julia$bin_dir,
> img_abs_path)  2: julia_setup()
>
> Possible actions: 1: abort (with core dump, if enabled) 2: normal R
> exit 3: exit R without saving workspace 4: exit R saving workspace
> ERROR: Selection:

```
Macbook Pro 
Processor - 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7
Memory - 2 GB 2667 MHz DDR4
OS - MacOS Big Sur v11.6
```

```
R version 4.1.1
Rstudio 2021.09.0 Build 351
Anaconda version 1.7.2
Julia 1.6
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It appears something happened to my PATH, python is working fine now in RStudio and likely due to recent OS update. Julia is still crashing it, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem (using `library(reticulate)`), with the same versions of R, RStudio and MacOS as you reported. My problem was solved by installing the previous version of RStudio, i.e., Version 1.4.1717.

Running my code in an R console or the IDE bundled with R also worked.